# Why exceptions don't popup from the event loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Please explain why the exception does not come out of the event loop in the example below. Thank you.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.t1 = 0
    def on_click(self):
# ZeroDivisionError
        self.t1 = 10 / 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG, filename = u"test.log", format = u"%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s")
    logging.info( u"Start application")
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    try:
        code = app.exec_()
    except Exception as exc:
        logging.error(exc, exc_info = True)
    logging.info( u"Stop application")
    sys.exit(code)
```

Comment: The code inside the `try` block doesn't raise the exception.

Comment: Why not ?
app.exec_() - start the event loop,
event loop - call on_click method,
on_click method - raised ZeroDivisionError

Comment: The event-loop doesn't call anything - it processes events. The signal-slot mechanism is completely separate, and doesn't require a running event-loop (except for cross-thread signals). If you want centralised exception handling, use `sys.excepthook`.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed